# Special treatment for first and last items in \seq_map_inline

Tags: expl3, programming

It is rather common to have to apply special treatment for first and last items of a sequence. I wonder what the best ways to treat these cases in `expl3`'s `\seq_map_inline`.

For instance, suppose I'd like to create the following tabular (ASCII art):

```
Words foo
      ---
      bar
      ---
      baz
```

where the words "foo", "bar", "baz" are the items of a sequence. This could be done the following way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\seq_new:N \l_my_sequence_seq

\seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_my_sequence_seq {foo,bar,baz}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_my_sequence_seq {
    \int_gincr:N \g_tmpa_int
    \int_compare:nNnT {\g_tmpa_int}={1}{Words}
    & #1
    \int_compare:nNnF {\g_tmpa_int}={\seq_count:N \l_my_sequence_seq}{\\\cline{2-2}}
  }
\end{tabular}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

But I wonder if there are better ways to achieve the same result.

Comment: Shouldn't the last item have not a following `cline`? I think, `\seq_map_inline` is the wrong way in a tabular environment

Comment: @ChristianHupfer If I'm right, that's the case: there isn't any `\cline` after "baz". Why wouldn't you recommend `\seq_map_inline` in a `tabular` environment and what would recommend instead?

Comment: \seq_map_inline:Nn is not really made for starting in one table cell (or say group) and stopping in another one.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Okay for a single cell but, here, the whole line is concerned.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest to remove the test for the `1st` item and popping the items from a temporary list in a `\seq_map_function:NN` approach rather.

The popping occurs inside a group, so `\l_tmpa_seq` is not really hurt in the mapping loop.

Note that `\bitouze_map_function:n` requires one argument (which is actually the current `\seq_item`, but this argument is not used at all here!)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\seq_new:N \l_my_sequence_seq

\seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_my_sequence_seq {foo,bar,baz}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_my_sequence_seq {
    \int_gincr:N \g_tmpa_int
    \int_compare:nNnT {\g_tmpa_int}={1}{Words}
    & #1
    \int_compare:nNnF {\g_tmpa_int}={\seq_count:N \l_my_sequence_seq}{\\\cline{2-2}}
  }
\end{tabular}


\seq_set_eq:NN \l_tmpa_seq \l_my_sequence_seq

\cs_new:Nn \bitouze_map_function:n {
  &\seq_gpop_left:NN \l_tmpa_seq \l_tmpa_tl 
  \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl \tabularnewline
  \seq_if_empty:NTF \l_tmpa_seq{% False branch
    \cline{2-2}
  }
}


\begin{tabular}{ll}
  Words 
  \seq_map_function:NN \l_tmpa_seq \bitouze_map_function:n
\end{tabular}


\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I guess you want to detach the last element of the sequence:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \l_db_wordlist_seq
\tl_new:N \l_db_wordlist_last_tl

\NewDocumentCommand{\wordlist}{m}
 {
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_db_wordlist_seq { #1 }
  \seq_pop_right:NN \l_db_wordlist_seq \l_db_wordlist_last_tl
  \begin{tabular}{ll}
  Words \seq_map_function:NN \l_db_wordlist_seq \__db_wordlist_do:n
  & \l_db_wordlist_last_tl
  \end{tabular}
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__db_wordlist_do:n { & #1 \\ \cline{2-2} }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\wordlist{foo,bar,baz}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If I understand well, your advise for the special treatment for the first and
last items of a sequence is to (1) pop and store them in `..._first_tl` and
`..._last_tl` token lists, (2) treat them through these token list and treat the
rest of the sequence with a (mapped) function?

Comment: @DenisBitouzé This depends on what you actually need to do; for this application you can wrap in a function the treatment of all elements except the last.